# direction of bent arrow in xy

Tags: xymatrix

This MWE

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\def\Lan{\text{Lan}}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\def\sX{\mathbb{X}}
\def\sY{\mathbb{Y}}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@C=2cm{
 & \sX\ar[r]^A\ar[d]_J  & \sY \\
\sX \ar[r]^B\ar[d]_J & \sY\ar[ur]_{\Lan_JA} &  \\
\sY\ar[ur]_{\Lan_JB} \ar`d[rr]`[uurr]_{\Lan_JA\circ B}[uurr]&  & 
}
\end{document}
```

produces the following  result:
[image]

I'm unable to let the arrow start from the right side of the lower $\mathbb Y$ (every combination of directions different than `` \ar`d[rr] `` has been useless). Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 6):

with `` \ar`r[rru] ``:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\def\Lan{\text{Lan}}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\def\sX{\mathbb{X}}
\def\sY{\mathbb{Y}}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@C=2cm{
 & \sX\ar[r]^A\ar[d]_J  & \sY \\
\sX \ar[r]^B\ar[d]_J & \sY\ar[ur]_{\Lan_JA} &  \\
\sY\ar[ur]_{\Lan_JB} \ar`r[rru]_{\Lan_JA\circ B}[uurr]&  & 
}
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But your picture is the same of the OP. You should change the direction of bent arrow.

Comment: @Sebastiano Read the question. The OP asks to start the arrow right of the lower Y, this is what I did. My picture is not the same as in the OP!!!!

Comment: I'm unable to let the arrow start from the right side of the lower $\mathbb Y$. The tip of the arrow should to end where there is the $\mathbb Y$ at the left bottom.

Comment: @Sebastiano No, the tip is at the end and not at the start.

Comment: @Sebastiano The question seems clear: the bent arrow should start from the right side of the Y at the bottom and end just below the Y at the top. Which is what steffen is doing.

Comment: @egreg Excuse me always for my bad English. Often I have misunderstood the questions :-(.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image: Result]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\def\Lan{\text{Lan}}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\def\sX{\mathbb{X}}
\def\sY{\mathbb{Y}}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@C=2cm{
                        & \sX\ar[r]^A\ar[d]_J   & \sY\ar`d[dd][ddll]_{\Lan_JA\circ B}\\
\sX \ar[r]^B\ar[d]_J    & \sY\ar[ur]_{\Lan_JA}  &  \\
\sY                     &                       & 
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The direction seems wrong.

Comment: Can you please explain what the correct output should look like? It took me sometime to wrap my head around what was needed.

Comment: The arrow from the above-right Y to the below-left Y should be from below-left Y to above-right Y. Moreover, an arrow from the below-left Y to the central Y is missing.